# How to reduce bundle size of Plotly.js for 3D surface chart?

Tags: webpack, charts, plotly, plotly.js

I need to draw only a surface chart in 3D with [Plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js) library but the bundle size is too big ( ~2MB). So I decided to add only a partial bundle which they provided for 3D plots ( called [plotly gl3d](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md#plotlyjs-gl3d) ). The gl3d partial bundle contains trace modules scatter, scatter3d, surface, mesh3d, isosurface, volume, cone and streamtube. The size of is this bundle is ~500kB which is still big.

I decided to create my own [custom bundle](https://github.com/Rezakarimi66/plotly-webpack) with the help of webpack and only add the surface graph module like below.

```
var Plotly = require('plotly.js/lib/core.js');
Plotly.register([
    require('plotly.js/lib/surface'),
]);
module.exports = Plotly;
```

[Here](https://github.com/Rezakarimi66/plotly-webpack) you can find the full code in Github. But the custom bundle size is larger than what they have already provided. It's about 1.5 MB! It seems that they are doing much more than simple bundling. Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you build your bundle using `npm run webpack-prod`? webpack should minify the code in production mode.

Comment: @mit Yes, I am using `webpack --mode=production`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the developers of this library, I found out that the only possible way to reducing my bundle size is gzip compression. For more info, you could see [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4891)